# Trying to concatenate a comma delimited list from one column with three table joins and getting duplicates

Tags: sql, ssms

Here is an example of my tables:

items

```
+----------+---------------+
| txt_item | txt_unique_id |
+----------+---------------+
| Circle   |             1 |
| Square   |             2 |
| Triangle |             3 |
+----------+---------------+
```

tag_master

```
+---------+----------+
| txt_tag | opt_type |
+---------+----------+
| red     | color    |
| blue    | color    |
| yellow  | color    |
| large   | size     |
| medium  | size     |
| small   | size     |
+---------+----------+
```

item_tags

```
+---------+---------------+
| txt_tag | txt_unique_id |
+---------+---------------+
| red     |             1 |
| blue    |             1 |
| large   |             1 |
| small   |             1 |
| red     |             2 |
| yellow  |             2 |
| small   |             2 |
| medium  |             2 |
| red     |             3 |
| yellow  |             3 |
+---------+---------------+
```

I want to return this:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| Circle   | red, blue, large, small    |
| Square   | red, yellow, small, medium |
| Triangle | red, yellow                |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

This is what I am getting:

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
| Circle   | red, red, red, blue, large, small, small    |
| Square   | red, red, red, yellow, yellow, small, small |
| Triangle | red, red, red, yellow, yellow               |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Here is where I am at:

```
CREATE TABLE #screening_tags
  (
     txt_unique_id VARCHAR(36),
     tags          VARCHAR(1000)
  )

INSERT INTO #screening_tags
            (txt_unique_id,
             tags)
(SELECT txt_unique_id,
        ( STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + t.txt_tag
                 FROM   item_tags t
                        JOIN tag_master_ tm
                          ON t.txt_tag = tm.txt_tag
                        JOIN items i
                          ON t.txt_unique_id = i.txt_unique_id
                 ORDER  BY opt_type,
                           txt_tage
                 FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') )
 FROM   item_tags t)

SELECT *
FROM   #screening_tags
```

I also tried using COALESCE, but I am missing something. I need a DISTINCT or something, but everything I have tried doesn't work. I can't use a DISTINCT or a TOP 1 if I want to ORDER BY the opt_type. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the join onto tag_master - looking at your expected results, you don't need anything from that table. In fact, you don't seem to need any joins.

```
    CREATE TABLE #screening_tags
      (
         txt_unique_id VARCHAR(36),
         tags          VARCHAR(1000)
      )

    INSERT INTO #screening_tags
                (txt_unique_id,
                 tags)
    (SELECT txt_unique_id,
            ( STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + t.txt_tag
                     FROM   items i
                     where t.txt_unique_id = i.txt_unique_id
                     ORDER  BY opt_type,
                               txt_tag
                     FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') )
     FROM   item_tags t)

    SELECT *
    FROM   #screening_tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what DB you're on, but if it's Postgres, give this a try:

```
SELECT i.item, string_agg(DISTINCT tm.text_tag,',') AS txt_tag_agg
FROM items i
INNER JOIN item_tags it ON i.txt_unique_id = it.txt_unique_id
INNER JOIN tag_master tm ON it.txt_tag = tm.text_tag
GROUP BY i.item
```

The `string_agg` function will build an aggregate string of the specified row values grouped by the `GROUP BY` column.

Comment: Calm down buddy.  I had no idea SSMS = SQL Server.  Besides this can give an idea of the logic for a possible solution, even if it doesn't work on his specific DB.

Comment: I'm with you, ravioli!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on SQL-server >= 2017, the [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) is now available.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8628/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
select i.txt_item , string_agg(it.txt_tag, ',')
from items i
inner join item_tags it
  on i.txt_unique_id = it.txt_unique_id
inner join tag_master tm
  on tm.txt_tag = it.txt_tag
where opt_type = 'color'
group by i.txt_item
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8628/2/0)**:

```
| txt_item |            |
|----------|------------|
|   Circle |   red,blue |
|   Square | red,yellow |
| Triangle | red,yellow |
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am on 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery will at least work on sql server, mysql, sqlite and postgresql:

```
select i.txt_item, 
(select string_agg(txt_tag, ',') 
from item_tags it where i.txt_unique_id=it.txt_unique_id) as txt_tag
from items i
```

returns:

```
txt_item    txt_tag
Circle      red,blue,large,small
Square      red,yellow,small,medium
Triangle    red,yellow
```

On mysql use group_concat(txt_tag) instead of string_agg.
On postgres, use array_agg(txt_tag).

[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/19ce3/6)

Comment: Updated the answer to work with sql server. And Eric, I dont think work is written with three exclamation marks, keep it down, OK?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I had to link the STUFF subquery to the main query in the WHERE clause

```
CREATE TABLE #screening_tags
  (
     txt_unique_id VARCHAR(36),
     tags          VARCHAR(1000)
  )

INSERT INTO #screening_tags
            (txt_unique_id,
             tags)
(SELECT txt_unique_id,
        ( STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.txt_tag
                 FROM   item_tags t1
                       WHERE t.txt_unique_id = t2.txt_unique_id
                 FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') )
 FROM   item_tags t2)

SELECT *
FROM   #screening_tags

+----------+----------------------------+
| Circle   | red, blue, large, small    |
| Square   | red, yellow, small, medium |
| Triangle | red, yellow                |
+----------+----------------------------+
```